# Short horror story about a glass monster

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I have been searching for a story I read in the early 2000s. I have a vague memory about the story being about a glass blower finding a weird spot of sand on the beach and making something out of it. It becomes a monster that can shape shift. I remember it turning into a bathtub and a gargoyle at one point.